# If the Subscriber is in a Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a requirement where I need to inject contacts into a couple of journeys.

However, at various points I need to check in which a all journeys a contact is already in and then take some decisions.

how can I check the various journeys in which a contact is?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the database that is used by Journey Builder to store Contact activities is not publicly available.

The only solution is to include an Update Contact Data Activity in your Interaction to update a field in a Data Extension. For example:

1. create a nullable boolean field in a DE named 'entered Welcome Journey'
2. ensure that this DE exists in a 1:1 relationship in an Attribute Group
3. set the Update Contact Data Activity to update the boolean value from the field in Step 1 to 'true'

Alternatively you can use [Data Binding](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/interaction-specification/how-data-binding-works.html) with the Update Contact Data Activity to update a DE text field with the Id of the Interaction, by pasting the following code into the value of the Update Contact Data Activity: `{{Context.DefinitionId}}`

Each Interaction has a unique DefinitionId. This will update this field with the DefinitionId of the current Interaction. You can then use the value of the DefinitionId to identify which Interaction the Contact is in.